# Python flask bootstrap выдает ошибку Could not build url for endpoint '/static' with values

Tags: python, bootstrap, flask

Подключил flask-bootstrap к проекту. Все прописал не менял содержимое файла base.html который находится в bootstrape. Запускаю выдает ошибку

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/static' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'static' instead?
```

затем поменял в файле base.html надписи bootstrap.static на static, но все также выдает ошибку при запуске

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='css/normalize.css') }}
```

url_for первый параметр это папка а второй путь
может что то не так делаю ?

Answer (score 1):

Укажите в файле конфигурации или инициализации, что же такое STATIC и где он находится.

В `url_for` 'static' - это не папка, а имя view. Эта view уже находится в flask по умолчанию, но нужно прописать в конфигурации путь к вашим статическим файлам, чтобы они смогли работать.

В configuration.py (или как у вас называется файл конфигурации):

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"))
```

и в __init__.py в корне проекта:

```
import configuration

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(configuration)
```